# C# Split Word.Table to fit page width

Tags: c#, sql, interop, office-interop

I'm using C# winform app to generate a document, and building tables dynamically from the DB. However, sometimes the table have too many columns to fit in the page and the table expands outside of the page.

Can I split the table somehow?

For example:
let say I have table with 10 rows and 14 columns (first column is the category). I would like to create two table of 8 columns where the first column is the same for both tables.

Comment: can you use css to do this

Comment: Couldn't you just count columns (amount which is received from database) and if its greater than 8 => split rows to half and create two tables....

Comment: I would like to know how can I split the table if I already have the full table from DB?

Comment: If you're using a `DataTable`, you can split it by rows, but not columns. That's something you'd have to do manually.

Comment: I'm using Word.Table, can I auto shrink the table so it will wrap text in order to fit the page width?